# Removing the numerics

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

col1

```
ABX67206
ABX67245
ABX67275
ABX67312
ABX67313
ABX67333
ABX67335
```

excel sheet, where we have a column called `policy_prefix (datatype - nvarchar)`.

For example: I have `col1 - ABX67206` I need the output as `ABX` means to remove all the numeric values from the column.

some times i get the records like that  col1-'ABXTU02' where I need the output as 'ABXTU'

here in the question means remove only numeric values and the length remains same

the out put is like

col1

ABX
ABX
ABX
ABX
ABX
ABXTU
ABXTU
ABX
ABXTUYT

like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @tbl table (i varchar(50))

insert into @tbl values ('qwe1456'),('w4'),('op75'),('123')

SELECT i, LEFT(i,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',i)-1)
FROM  @tbl
```

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk What about value like `ASD*(123)` :)?

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk THe policy numbers are obviously prefixed with alpha characters then suffixed with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 10 times `REPLACE` function, i.e.:

```
select replace(replace(replace(column, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '') ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text in *col1* is always on the same format (3 characters, followed by any number of digits), you can use the substring function:

SELECT x = SUBSTRING('ABX67206', 1, 3);

Which will return `ABX` in this case.

Comment: If we knew it's the first 3 chars... left() would be clearer.